# An unhandled exception in the designer

Tags: visual-studio-2019, unhandled-exception

I've created a project in Visual Studio 2019 which has several user controls in a form called `Home`.

All goes right until today. After rebuilding my project `Home` form shows an error saying

```
The control system.windows.forms.form has thrown an unhandled exception in the designer and has been desabled. 
Exception :
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file c:\program files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\common7\ide\database\pharmacy.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on unc share.
```

I checked the connection code, and it looks ok. But still the error isn't solved.

Code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\Final Project BCA\PharmacyManagementSystemCSharp\Database\pharmacy.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open()
String str = "Select max(id) from supp;";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.Read())
{
String val = dr[0].ToString();
if (val == "")
{
.....
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source= (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\Final Project BCA\PharmacyManagementSystemCSharp\Database\pharmacy.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            try
            {
                String str = "Insert into supp(name,email,mobile,addr,s_code) values('" + Sup_Name.Text + "','" + Sup_Email.Text + "','" + Sup_Mobile.Text + "','" + Sup_Add.Text + "','" + Sup_Code.Text + "');";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                String str1 = "select max(ID) from supp;";
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(str1, con);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Inserted Supplier Data SuccessFully..");
                    using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\Final Project BCA\PharmacyManagementSystemCSharp\Database\pharmacy.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
                    {
                        String str2 = "Select * from supp";
                        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(str2, con1);
                        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        SupplierDataGV.DataSource = new BindingSource(dt, null);
                    }
                    Sup_Name.Text = "";
                    Sup_Code.Text = "";
                    Sup_Email.Text = "";
                    Sup_Mobile.Text = "";
                    Sup_Add.Text = "";

                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It sounds like somewhere in your code base something is trying to attach the MDF at `c:\program files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\common7\ide\database\pharmacy.mdf` and you also are trying to attach to one at `D:\Final Project BCA\PharmacyManagementSystemCSharp\Database\pharmacy.mdf`  - you can't have two database of the same name attached at the same time in an instance.

Comment: Yes I understand that but i cant can't figure out where it happened. I also mention the code i used for database connection. i have multiple buttons and for every button i make a connection separately, Is there any way to make the connection one time which can be access by multiple buttons from multiple user controls.

Comment: And also in this code is there any way to close the connection, after finishing the process of each button so next button can create a fresh connection? my all other user controls are work fine when i Build or rebuild the project, the problem occurs only on that form.  help me. I am stack with this problem.

Comment: Perhaps look around on the form designer for this form for a control that is sneakily using the wrong datasource. You can probably do a Find across your entire solution too to find the culprit. For your connections issue, you have a decent amount of connections in this one form going on. Try to make use of `using` statements for all of them. You currently are manually handling some connections, while using a `using` for others.